# Variables opcionales en mysqli_stmt_bind_param()

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, datos

Trabajo con PHP 7.4 y MariaDB (MySQL) 8. A ver si alguien puede asistirme.

¿Cómo agregar variables opcionalmente a **mysqli_stmt_bind_param()**?

Ejemplo:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param(
                       $ystat,
                       "issss",
                       $ys_V1,
                       $ys_V2,
                       $ys_V3,
                       $ys_V4,
                       $ys_ID
                      );
```

No todas las veces las variables *$ys_V1, $ys_V2, $ys_V3 y $ys_V4* irán en la sentencia, aunque también puede ser que algunas veces se requieran todas.

Siempre irá **al menos una**, que puede ser cualquiera, pero no siempre irán todas.

En unas ocasiones el *Bind* podría quedar:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param(
                       $ystat,
                       "issss",
                       $ys_V1,
                       $ys_V2,
                       $ys_V3,
                       $ys_V4,
                       $ys_ID
                      );
```

En otras ocasiones podría ser:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param(
                       $ystat,
                       "iss",
                       $ys_V1,
                       $ys_V4,
                       $ys_ID
                      );
```

Y en otras, quizá podría quedar:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param(
                       $ystat,
                       "ss",
                       $ys_V4,
                       $ys_ID
                      );
```

O cualquier combinación de esas.

¿Cómo construir *mysqli_stmt_bind_param()* para que se agreguen algunas y otras no, o todas según el caso?

Intenté hacerlo con **if** para validar los datos, pero *mysqli_stmt_bind_param()* no acepta valores sino referencias (variables).

He intentado hacerlo de dos formas con **call_user_func_array()** pero también me arroja error de referencias y, cuando lo uso con referencias, me dice:

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
> callback, class 'mysqli_stmt' does not have a method
> 'mysqli_stmt_bind_param' in script.php on line 3000.

Si alguien pudiera, por favor, indicarme cómo poner variables opcionalmente en **mysqli_stmt_bind_param()**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estas explicando cómo controlas las variables que quieres poner. Es allí donde debemos crear la estructura interna del **mysqli_stmt_bind_param()**, para luego pasarla como parámetro.

Sin esos datos esta respuesta es solo especulación de tu escenario real y puede contener fallos facilmente.

Se me ocurre el siguiente modo, suponiendo que las variables esten en un array inicial predefinidas de este modo:

```
$posibles_variables = [
  'ys_V1' => 'i',
  'ys_V2' => 's',
  'ys_V3' => 's',
  'ys_V4' => 's',
  'ys_ID' => 's'
]
```

que luego recorreremos antes de la sentencia para irlas agregando a otro array que tendrá el contenido de los parámetros de las variables:

```
$variables_validas = [];
$tipos_concatenados = '';
foreach($posibles_variables as $variable=>$tipo) {
    if (isset(${$variable})) {
        $variables_validas[] = ${$variable});
        $tipos_concatenados .= $tipo;
    }
}
```

Para ello hemos usado la sintaxis de [variables variables](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.variables.variable.php): `${$variable}`.

Con eso conseguimos un array con las variables que estan definidas denominado **$variables_validas** y a la vez la concatenación de cada uno de sus tipos en una variable de string que denominamos **$tipos_concatenados**.

Y ahora ya podemos montar la sentencia de este modo:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param( $ystat, $tipos_concatenados, ...$variables_validas);
```

donde usamos el operador **splat** `...` para desempaquetar el array $variables_validas y pasarlo como argumentos ([enlace a su documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list)).

No tengo un lugar donde probarlo, así que como decia, quizás tiene fallos, pero igualmente espero pueda ayudarte con la idea.